# Rails: Is it possible to organize code in a subfolder without create a namespace for it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdirectory, directory-structure

Rails uses a convention that each custom subfolder needs to became a module, for example:

```
--apps/
----blog/
------controllers
--------my_controller.rb
```

In the above case, to call the controller I need to call: `Blog::Controllers::MyController`

But what I want is to avoid use `Controllers` as a namespace, to call the controller is this way: `Blog::MyController`

Is it possible?

Some context: I'm working in a large codebase and we are starting to try to create a new module in a separate structure, similar how [Shopify](https://shopify.engineering/deconstructing-monolith-designing-software-maximizes-developer-productivity) did.

Comment: I've found a solution that seems being working. I'm using `autoload` from `ActiveSupport` in my `Blog` module.

`autoload :MyController, "#{Rails.root}/apps/blog/controllers/my_controller"`

Comment: If you try to follow Shopify's way, you'd better use Rails Engine instead of creating a new namespace under the `/app`.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

https://shopify.engineering/shopify-monolith